# Iterar sobre um array e salvar em um dict

Tags: python

Dado esse array:

```py
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Estou querendo iterá-lo para contar valores em cada linha e depois salva-los por linha.
O código abaixo está fazendo a soma geral. Gostaria de ter a contagem por linha.

```py
def count(image):
    array = np.array(image)
    array[[ array == 0 ]] = 1
    array[[ array == 255 ]] = 0
    for row in array:
        unique, counts = np.unique(array[row,] , return_counts=True)
        d = dict(zip(unique, counts))
    return new
```

O resultado:

```py
{0: 234710, 1: 515}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia,
Sua resposta está quase correta, para que seu script funcione você deve colocar o `unique` apenas em `row` não em `array[row,]`, também não existe um identificador da linha, você pode criar um dicionário para cada linha, ou uma lista em cada posição um dicionário para a linha correspondente:

uma lista com um dicionario para cada linha:

```
def count(image):
    array = np.array(image)
    array[[ array == 0 ]] = 1
    array[[ array == 255 ]] = 0
    colecao = list()
    for row in array:
        unique, counts = np.unique(row , return_counts=True)
        d = dict(zip(unique, counts))
        colecao.append(d)
```

um dicionário para cada linha:

```
def count(image):
    array = np.array(image)
    array[[ array == 0 ]] = 1
    array[[ array == 255 ]] = 0
    count = 0
    colecao = dict()
    for row in array:
        unique, counts = np.unique(row , return_counts=True)
        d = dict(zip(unique, counts))
        colecao[count] = d
        count += 1
```

Verifique se alguma delas é útil para você.

Comment: Completei a primeira alternativa  com colecao = [] no início e return(colecao) no final e deu certo.

Comment: que bom que deu certo amigo, se a resposta lhe ajudou curta ela e marque como resposta, assim ajuda a outros responderem suas dúvidas. Abraços amigo.